# Sum up table column values satisfying two row-conditions

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table

Below is my data in an Excel table:

```
+-------------+--------------+----------+
| Client Name | Sales Person | Net Sale |
+-------------+--------------+----------+
| ABC         | Jack         | 20,000   |
| BGS         | Sonia        | 38,888   |
| ABC         | Mira         |  6,744   |
| BGS         | Jack         | 32,000   |
| KNJ         | Mira         |  4,500   |
| ABC         | Jack         |  8,600   |
| KNJ         | Sam          | 56,000   |
+-------------+--------------+----------+
```

I would like to convert this data into the format:

```
+-------------+--------+--------+-------+---------+
| Client Name |  Jack  | Sonia  | Mira  |   Sam   |
+-------------+--------+--------+-------+---------+
| ABC         | 28,600 |        | 6,744 |         |
| BGS         | 32,000 | 38,888 |       |         |
| KNJ         |        |        | 4,500 | 56,000  |
+-------------+--------+--------+-------+---------+
```

The requirement is to generate a new table, crossing each row for `Client Name` with columns for `Sales Person`, and create a new table showing `Net Sale` values summing each `Sales Person`'s values by each `Client Name`.

For example: in the case of `Jack` and `ABC` we have two sales, so we add the values and display the result: `28600` (sum of: 20,000 + 8,600).

Please help me out with formula, preferably without VBA.

Comment: Is your data in a string format which needs to be broken down? Please clarify. The result - is it expected to be a string or a table format?

Comment: Client name Sales Person Net Sale
ABC                 Jack                    20,000 
BGS                 Sonia           38,888 
ABC                 Mira                     6,744 
BGS                 Jack                   32,000 
KNJ                 Mira                     4,500 
ABC                Jack                     8,600 
KNJ                Sam                   56,000

Comment: Have you ever used Pivot Tables?  I think they might be helpful for your problem.

Comment: Although this can be done with formulas, the use of Pivot Table as answered by @pnuts is more efficient and practical because the pivot table will get automatically updated for new Clients and Sales Persons, while with the formulas you will have to manually update and copy the formulas to extend the output to the range required.

Answer (score 1):

This cries out for a PivotTable:

[image: SO32796273 example]